# Memory Error:While reading a large .txt file from BLOB in python

Tags: python, pandas, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

I am trying to read a large (~1.5 GB) .txt file from Azure blob in python which is giving Memory Error. Is there a way in which I can read this file in an efficient way?

Below is the code that I am trying to run:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import time

STORAGEACCOUNTNAME= '*********'
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= "********"

CONTAINERNAME= '******'
BLOBNAME= 'path/to/blob'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME, account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

start = time.time()
blobstring = blob_service.get_blob_to_text(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME).content

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blobstring))
end = time.time()

print("Time taken = ",end-start)
```

Below are last few lines of the error:

```
---> 16 blobstring = blob_service.get_blob_to_text(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME)
     17 
     18 #df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blobstring))

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py in get_blob_to_text(self, container_name, blob_name, encoding, snapshot, start_range, end_range, validate_content, progress_callback, max_connections, lease_id, if_modified_since, if_unmodified_since, if_match, if_none_match, timeout)
   2378                                       if_none_match,
   2379                                       timeout)
-> 2380         blob.content = blob.content.decode(encoding)
   2381         return blob
   2382 

MemoryError:
```

How can I read a file of size ~1.5 GB in Python from a Blob container? Also, I want to have an optimum runtime for my code.

Comment: looks like you've run out of ram, what I would do in your situation is read in the top 50 rows and see your `dtypes` and `columns` you can then choose your columns and `dtypes` which will make loading quicker. If you don't specify your `dtypes` pandas will guess which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumed that there is enough memory in your machine, and according to the `pandas.read_csv` API reference below, you can directly read the csv blob content into pandas dataframe by the csv blob url with sas token.

[image]

Here is my sample code as refenece for you.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import pandas as pd

account_name = '<your storage account name>'
account_key = '<your storage account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = '<your csv blob name>'

url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"

service = BaseBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
# Generate the sas token for your csv blob
token = service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),)

# Directly read the csv blob content into dataframe by the url with sas token
df = pd.read_csv(f"{url}?{token}")
print(df)
```

I think it will avoid to copy memory few times when read the text content and convert it to a `file-like` object `buffer`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The current runtime of this code is ~6 minutes for ~1.5 GB file. Can we improve the runtime further?

Comment: Is BaseBlobService depreciated? I cannot seem to install or import it.